# if condition in ajax not working for serialize()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am working on building a site. I have got some problems with making AJAX requests which I have not much knowledge. I'm trying to post data via AJAX, my code looks like this:

```
$('.submitsearchbtn').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '',
        type: 'post',
        data: $("#a").serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data == 1) {
                $('body').load('findpals.php');
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#errors_three').css("display", "block");
                    $("#errors_three").fadeTo(10000, 0).slideUp(50, 0);
                }, 1000);
            }
            if (data == 2) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

`#a` is the id of my `form` and I'm using `serialize()` which is holding my form `input name=''` values and it is posting to the same page as I have left the forms `url` attribute blank.

Now my problem is that every thing works fine, my PHP side is catching the post data on `$_POST['.....']` and it does return value `1` if error and `2` if success. However when I use that `if` condition and checking my `data = 1` (error) or `2` (success) there isn't anything happening.

My PHP returns me `2` for success but that if condition isn't letting me inside that code block. When I removed both `if` conditions and set `console.log(data)` alone inside the `success` handler then on inspect element console side I see '2'. So, why isn't the `if` condition working? Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: @RDay to what errors are you referring, the code looks fine to me.

Comment: Looks valid to me @RDay

Comment: Check the datatypes that is being returned. Assuming they are strings, you should try `if (data == '1')` or you could explicitly convert it to an integert: `if (parseInt(data, 10) == 1)`

Comment: also could be extra whitespace being returned try `data = data.trim()` before checking using @RoryMcCrossan suggestion

Comment: @charlietfl good point. OP, I would suggest you look in to returning JSON instead of plaintext as it will avoid typing/whitespace issues completely.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry, you're right. I misread it and putting it through JSLint, seeing a load of red strengthened that view.

Comment: Try `if (/1/.test(data))` , `if (/2/.test(data))`

Comment: @RDay code are fine  :) I tested just now jslint.com as you said but there wasn't any changes after solving those errors.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sir thanks for your edit.

Comment: @SOuřaanGřg yes, you're right. I've deleted my comment to reflect that.

Comment: omg @guest271314 what was that?It worked for me :D Tnq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) to test for occurrence of `1` , `2` in `data`

`if (/1/.test(data))` , `if (/2/.test(data))`

Comment: It worked for me :) what was happening on my code earlier sir?How did this worked on that if condition can u explain in little more sir?

Comment: @SOuřaanGřg Not entirely certain what was returned as `data` ? Though `data` may have included a space character , newline, tab or other character , returning `false` for condition `data == 1` , as `data` may have also included additional character before or after `1` . `.test()` with `RegExp` `/1/` returns `true` if `1` found in `data` ; ignores both if other characters before or after `1` in `data` and  if `1` type is `String` or `Number`

Comment: from php side echo "1"; for error and echo "2"; was for success.Ignores mean it will escape other characters before and after 1 and take only 1 as data?

Comment: @SOuřaanGřg _"Ignores mean it will escape other characters before and after 1 and take only 1 as data?"_ `RegExp` `/1/` should only check for match of `1` from input.  Try at `console` `/1/.test("\r\n\t1 ")// true` , `/1/.test(1)// true` , `"1" == "\r\n\t1 "//false` . See `RegExp` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp , Comparison operators https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: sir when i did `console.log(data);` on console I found whole html file where there along with that 2 which was a success indication.I guess now I had some problem on my received data.Or I did some mistake on getting data from that form?How can we get only 2 now in this case sir?

Comment: `url: ''` returns current document

Comment: sir i was echoing some other html elements too before that echo "2"; so.. what can i do now?I have to post on that same page so, i leaved that url attribute blank but as you know now I'm getting all html as a data how can i only select 2 now for that all?

Comment: Is `js` at post not returning expected results ?

Comment: i tested your regexp and checked the result on console but it brings true on both if condition after that I checked what data is returned by using  `console.log(data);` inside that `success: function (data) {.......}` and I found that my data was taking all html data with that 2.It is returning value   but I guess it's returning other html element too which where before that echo "2";

Comment: @SOuřaanGřg Not certain how `2` get printed within `html` `document` ? Can post text of server side process at original Question ?

Comment: Some are written on html and some aren't written by normal html only.Some div,input are echo by php.I had some condition where i need to check on database so..i used php and echo some html div,input too.Oho..so i can't get only 2 as a data in this way right sir?Isn't there idea to solve this?

Comment: Try to call `echo "2"` before `html` , adjust `RegExp` to `if (/^2/.test(data))` ; `^` indicates characters is at beginning of string

Comment: sir i'm so much happy that i did it :D `success: function(data){
        var d = $(data).find('.done').text();
        if(d == '2'){
           $('.userdetailbox').css("display","none");
        }` was the working code for my case :D

Comment: i made a class on my php side where I used to echo "2"; only at earlier but this time I added a class `echo "<span class='done'>2</span>";` like that and checked my data text has string of 2 :D

Answer (score 1):

Try $.trim(data). Sometimes the response has bit of whitespace which may cause this behaviour